# How to search for all except certain strings using like (or different solution welcomed)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

For now, I need to filter out rows with certain text strings. 
E.g. for string that is given in this format: 'taxes, car' - I need to filter out all rows that include either "taxes" or "cars" in the description of the row.
I have come up with this:

```
SELECT
             TransactionId
            ,t.DocumentID
            ,t.DocumentDescription
FROM [Transaction] t
INNER JOIN (SELECT CONCAT('%',[Value], '%') AS [Value] 
            FROM STRING_SPLIT(N'taxes,cars',',')
            ) w
ON t.[DocumentDescription] NOT LIKE w.[Value]
```

This does not work at all, since it matches both of the splitted strings and filters out the row only when both of the strings are included in the description of the row. 
Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: Do you want to match the text snippets or words? For example `'cars'` will match `'unsightly scars'` and `'Vicarship is my goal'` if you don't parse words out of the string.

Comment: the snippets are fine, the dataset is taken into consideration :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got me the result I wanted!

```
SELECT 1,2,3 FROM [Transaction]
EXCEPT
SELECT 1,2,3 FROM [Transaction] t
    INNER JOIN (INNER JOIN(SELECT CONCAT('%',[Value], '%') AS [Value] FROM 
            STRING_SPLIT(N'cars,taxes',',')) w
    ON t.Description LIKE w.Value
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `NOT EXISTS`:

```
WITH w as (
      SELECT value as word
      FROM STRING_SPLIT(N'taxes,cars', ',')
     )
SELECT t.*
FROM [Transaction] t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM w
                  WHERE t.DocumentDescription LIKE CONCAT('%', w.word, '%')
                 );
```

Note that because of the use of `LIKE` this query has to scan the entire table.  You might want to rethink your data model, perhaps using a full text index or breaking the description into words if you have large tables and performance is an issue.

Comment: hey, thank you for reply! 
 what exactly is "s"
as in "SELECT 1 FROM s WHERE..."

Comment: @RAH-66 . . . It was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you were open to other ideas... What you are looking to do can be done without a splitter function (e.g. STRING_SPLIT in your example). If you wanted to let your filter expression (`'taxes,cars'`) come in as a parameter then you could use SRING_SPLIT. Note the sample data and both examples below:

```
DECLARE @Transaction TABLE 
(
  TransactionId       INT IDENTITY,
  DocumentDescription VARCHAR(1000)
);
INSERT @Transaction (DocumentDescription) VALUES('Blah, blah... cars...'), ('Yada, yada... taxes'),('Blah blah...');

-- Without a Splitter Function (e.g. SPLIT_STRING)
SELECT t.TransactionId, t.DocumentDescription
FROM @Transaction AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT      1
  FROM        @Transaction
  CROSS JOIN  (VALUES('taxes'),('cars')) AS srch(Item)
  WHERE       CHARINDEX(srch.Item,t.DocumentDescription) > 0 
);

-- Using Split String
SELECT t.*
FROM @Transaction AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM  STRING_SPLIT(N'taxes,cars', ',') AS w
  WHERE CHARINDEX(w.[value],DocumentDescription) > 0
);
```